# Change iphone settings based on device capabilities

Tags: iphone, objective-c, settings

Is it possible to hide certain application settings in standard Settings application based on current device capabilities? For example user can choose whether to show compass calibration UI or not, but I don't want to show this setting if device does not have a compass (e.g. iPhone 3g).

Well, I think that is not possible actually but may be I missed something simple here (or any other available options)...

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, and it's recommended to do this. One example is to check whether the device can make phone calls:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:"]]) {
    // do stuff with a phone number
}
```

There are other ways to check device capabilities. Check the documentation to find them. For example, the `CLLocation` docs have a `+(BOOL)headingAvailable` method, which tells you if you can find out the heading.

Comment: Yes, I know how to disable related features **inside** application. What I want to do is to hide preference outside my app - which is defined in Settings.bundle and displayed in standard Settings app.